# Making a javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I am making a countdown timer where the text for Days Hours Minutes Seconds is just below to their respective values. Also it must be responsive too. I have some code below:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"


  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "<h1>" + days + " <span> days </span>: " + hours + "    <span>hours</span>: " + minutes + " <span>minutes </span>: <font color='red'>" + seconds + "<span> s</span></font> </h1>";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div align="center" id="timer"></div>
```

My code has a problem in the case that the day symbol D is on left of the Day value but I want it to be on right. I mean just like picture below [image: j]

Comment: Please explain where you have problem. What is not working?

Comment: I had edited the question please do look

Comment: The `d` is on the right for me

Comment: Are you just asking how to position the text below the numbers, as in the screenshot?  There's nothing wrong with the countdown code itself?

Comment: I don't see any D symbol in the picture you posted. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: So write HTML without the JavaScript that does what you want and than put it into the JavaScript code....

Comment: Yes I have no problem in code but just want to position text below.

Comment: So write HTML that does it....

Comment: Yes but it must be just down the values and it is not possible with just html. If possible could you please provide me how its done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text in `<div>` to create a line break. Secondly create a function which takes `text`,`value` and `color` as parameter and return html string.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

function timePart(val,text,color="black"){
  return `<h1 class="timer" style="color:${color};">${val}<div>${text}</div></h1>`
}

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
 var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

 // Display the result in the element with id="demo"

 let res = timePart(days,'days') + timePart(hours,'hours') + timePart(minutes,'Mins')  + timePart(seconds,'Seconds','red');
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = res

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
 if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.timer{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed it according to your requirements. It's not exactly like the picture but I'm sure you can do a little bit of styling. Here is the snippet in action.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"


  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = days
  document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = hours
  document.getElementById("mm").innerHTML = minutes
  document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML = seconds

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
h1 span {
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

p span {
  margin: 0px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <h1>
    <span id="dd"></span>:
    <span id="hh"></span>:
    <span id="mm"></span>:
    <span style="color:red;" id="ss"></span>
  </h1>
  <p>
    <span>Days</span>
    <span>Hours</span>
    <span>Minutes</span>
    <span>Seconds</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes its working but I want the text likes D M H and S be below the respective value of Day Hour Month and Time as in my picture posted.

Comment: Here you go. I (almost) fixed it!